# Content inside absolute div won't display?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a div that displays information when its relative parent is clicked. I have all the JS down to set this up, but before I dive into that, I can't seem to get any content to display inside of the absolute div holding all of the content. Below, I have some code and a JSFiddle recreating the issue (and, yes, my inner-text class doesn't have a height, but with or without it, the issue still remains). Is there a reason behind this/can I get this to work. Here we go:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="project" style="margin-bottom:368px;">
            <div id="p-inner" style="">
                <div class="inner-text">
                <p>Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-container {
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.project {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    max-height: 386px;
    z-index: 2;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#p-inner {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 368px;
}
.inner-text {
    bottom: 0px;
    width :90%;
}
```

And here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6am4ovqk/
I'm almost positive if I get some sleep, the answer will slap me in the face tomorrow morning but I still want to help out others with a similar issue by posing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is font-size: 0; in `.content-container`

```
.content-container {
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Give some font-size greater than 0. It will display.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6am4ovqk/1/)**

Comment: It's the sleep, then. So sad I missed that. Thank you.